# Trailer tire weight rating

Tags: tires, trailer

[https://www.amazon.com/2-Pack-Trailer-Wheel-ST205-75D14/dp/B074MHFC2C/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B074MHFC2C)

Said tire is rated:

- Tire Weight Rating: 1760 Lbs. Max. Pressure: 50 PSI

Does this mean that one pair of tires (on a single axle) can support 2X1760 lbs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, yes. However, there is the rating of the axle itself to consider. The axle, more or less, will have a different rating. Make sure you take into account this before you decide whatever you're putting the tires onto might be able to handle the load.

Comment: Always grateful to hear from @Paulster2's insight.   Thank you